# JS Smooth Scroll not working with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am having some issue with some code I have. I have a set of tabs that have content within each of them. When a user clicks at tab, i'd like it to open the tab content AND smooth scroll to the anchor that is in the tab content. Currently, I have the following code that opens the active tabs content and scrolls to the anchor. However, it won't smooth scroll, itll just jump to the anchor. Could someone help me so that it smooth scrolls to the anchor? I would appreciate any and all help.

[Current Fiddle that shows the jump](http://jsfiddle.net/ehj8naq6/3/)

[My website with a live example of what happens](http://firesuppressiontech.com/heated-sample-lines)

**Code**

```
var hrefname = null;

$('a').click(function () {
var $tab = $(this).closest('li')
if (!$tab.hasClass("active")) {
var tabNum = $tab.index();
var nthChild = tabNum + 1;
$("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
$("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active").hide();
$("ul#tab li:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active").show();
}
setTimeout(function () {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('[name="' + hrefname + '"]').offset().top
}, 500);
var href = $('a').attr('href');
console.log(href);
hrefname = href;
return false;
}, 10000);
});
```

**HTML Tabs**

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#features" class="smoothScroll">FEATURES</a>  </li>
<li><a href="#specs" class="smoothScroll">SPECIFICATIONS</a></li>
<li><a href="#config" class="smoothScroll">COMPARE CONFIGURATIONS</a></li>
```

```
<ul id="tab">
<li class="active">
    <a name="features"></a>Content 1
</li>

<li>
    <a name="specs"></a>Content 2
</li>

  <li>
    <a name="config"></a>Content 3
</li>
```

**CSS (for those interested)**

```
ul#tabs {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
}
ul#tabs li {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: solid 3px #ffffff;
padding: 5px 12px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-right: 55px;
color: #e5e5e5;
font-size: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
border-bottom: solid 3px #dd3333;
color: #000000;
}
ul#tabs li.active {
border-bottom: solid 3px #dd3333;
 color: #000000;
}
ul#tab {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul#tab li {
display: none;
}
ul#tab li.active {
display: block;
}
```